# Create a new array of multiple objects and array from a given array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, array-map

I have the following array

```
const CARS = 
[
  {make: "skoda", model: "kodiaq", color: "light-blue", id: "1002", category: "A"},
  {make: "skoda", model: "karoq", color: "green", id: "1008", category: "B"},
  {make: "renault", model: "clio", color: "grey", id: "1006", category: "A"},
  {make: "renault", model: "kangoo", color: "white", id: "1042", category: "C"},
  {make: "mazda", model: "cx3", color: "red", id: "1022", category: "C"},
  {make: "mazda", model: "cx30", color: "orange", id: "1106", category: "D"},
  {make: "ford", model: "explorer", color: "grey", id: "1162", category: "B"},
  {make: "ford", model: "edge", color: "red", id: "1862", category: "A"}
]
```

and I need to create a new array of objects grouped by the "category" property looking like this

```
const NEW_CARS = 
[
  {
    category: "A",
    data: 
     [
       {make: "skoda", model: "kodiaq", color: "light-blue", id: "1002", category: "A"},
       {make: "renault", model: "clio", color: "grey", id: "1006", category: "A"},
       {make: "ford", model: "edge", color: "red", id: "1862", category: "A"}
     ]
  },
  {
    category: "B",
    data: 
     [
       {make: "skoda", model: "karoq", color: "green", id: "1008", category: "B"},
       {make: "ford", model: "explorer", color: "grey", id: "1162", category: "B"},
     ]
  },
  {
    category: "C",
    data: 
     [
       {make: "renault", model: "kangoo", color: "white", id: "1042", category: "C"},
       {make: "mazda", model: "cx3", color: "red", id: "1022", category: "C"}
     ]
  },

  {
    category: "D",
    data: 
     [
       {make: "mazda", model: "cx30", color: "orange", id: "1106", category: "D"}
     ]
  }
]
```

I guess I would need to extract the list of categories from the original array and loop again creating a new array. I got lost, also not sure what would be the most performant approach since my array is actually pretty big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I `reduce` the CARS then `find` there equality.

Using a condition check their equality and if TRUE, I need to add it in an array of called *existing_category*. Else, I will add it in the array called *accumulator*.

Lastly, I will return the *accumulator* to see the result after the execution in **NEW_CARS**.

```js
const CARS = [
 {make: "skoda", model: "kodiaq", color: "light-blue", id: "1002", category: "A"},
 {make: "skoda", model: "karoq", color: "green", id: "1008", category: "B"},
 {make: "renault", model: "clio", color: "grey", id: "1006", category: "A"},
 {make: "renault", model: "kangoo", color: "white", id: "1042", category: "C"},
 {make: "mazda", model: "cx3", color: "red", id: "1022", category: "C"},
 {make: "mazda", model: "cx30", color: "orange", id: "1106", category: "D"},
 {make: "ford", model: "explorer", color: "grey", id: "1162", category: "B"},
 {make: "ford", model: "edge", color: "red", id: "1862", category: "A"}
];

const NEW_CARS = CARS.reduce((accumulator, car) => {
 const exist_category = accumulator.find(category => category.category === car.category)
 if (exist_category) {
   exist_category.data.push(car)
 } else {
   accumulator.push({category: car.category,data: [car]})
 }
 return accumulator;
}, []);
console.log(NEW_CARS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) then convert to your desired form:

```js
Object.entries(
  Object.groupBy(CARS, ({ category }) => category)
).map(([category, data]) => ({ category, data }))
```